# how to get a specific object in detailview django

Tags: python, django

i've these

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    users = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.users
```

between `ModelA` and `ModelB` there is no any relations

my forms.py

```
class ModelAForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ModelB.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ['name']

class ModelBForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ['users']
```

and in my views.py in `DetailView` of `ModelA` i have to return `balance` field in the `ModelB`

```
class ModelAView(DetailView):
    model = ModelA
    template_name = 'templates/tem.html'
    context_object_name = 'objs'
    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
    def get_object(self):
        id =  self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return get_object_or_404(ModelA,pk=id)
    # i need to get balance field in ModelB for the exact object , i tried this but doesn't work
    #def get_balance(self):
    #users = ModelB.objects.all().values_list('users',flat=True)
    #if ModelA.objects.filter(name__in=users):
    #    name = ModelA.objects.filter(name__in=users)
    #    balance = ModelB.objects.get(name=name).balance
    #    return balance
    #else:
    #    return False
```

but the above solution dont work and raised this error

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ModelA'

i need to display `balance` field in the `ModelA` `DetailView` !? is it possible please
note : i dont want to make any connection between `ModelA` and `ModelB`
i appreciate your helps ...
regards

Answer (score 2):

You can add [extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) from the `ModelB` in your DetailView

```
class ModelAView(DetailView):
    model = ModelA
    template_name = 'templates/tem.html'
    context_object_name = 'objs'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['balances'] = ModelB.objects.values_list('balance')
        return context
```

Comment: i need to return only the balance for that specific object , but it returns all

Comment: For this you need some relation between your models

Comment: i dont want make relations